# Matplotlib: Format for increasing Figsize, given code layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in my Jupyter notebook.  I have tried several different ways to change the figsize of the figure that I have found on the internet so far, but nothing seems to work.  Also, the way the objects are generated and changed in matplotlib don't really make sense to me anyways, so I am not sure where to go next...

Anyways, my code as it stands is:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix',fontsize=8, names=None,cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            plt.text(i, j, str(cm[i, j]), fontsize=fontsize)
    if names != None:
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, names)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')



confusion_matrix_path = 'mnist_cnn/main_project/CNN_Completed_Models/mnist_cnn_C_confusion.npy'
cmat = np.load(confusion_matrix_path)
plot_confusion_matrix(cmat,"MNIST Net C: Confusion Matrix",fontsize=8, names=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])




plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))  <----- This Line Here




plt.show()
```

The `plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))` line does nothing.  Nor does any of a number of fixes I have found.  How do I change the dimensions of this plot??

Comment: I would suggest using `%matplotlib notebook` so you get interactive figures instead of dead pngs.

Comment: and you are having issues with the state machine of `pyplot` and relying on using it's global state of 'current figure' to pass which figure to plot to into your plotting methods.  You should pass an `Axes` object into `plot_confusion_matrix` instead.  See http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Comment: and ``plt.figure` creates a new figure (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) not changes the size of an existing figure.

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy, and it makes no sense to me, but placing the `plt.figure(figsize=(a,b))` line before I plot anything makes it work.  I really don't understand how they structured these objects.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix',fontsize=8, names=None,cmap=plt.cm.Blues):


    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))     <---- Should Actually Go Here



    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            plt.text(i, j, str(cm[i, j]), fontsize=fontsize)
    if names != None:
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, names)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, names)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')



confusion_matrix_path = 'mnist_cnn/main_project/CNN_Completed_Models/mnist_cnn_C_confusion.npy'
cmat = np.load(confusion_matrix_path)
plot_confusion_matrix(cmat,"MNIST Net C: Confusion Matrix",fontsize=8, names=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])




plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))  <----- This Line Here




plt.show()
```

I don't know why it works that way...and I would def accept an answer that explains it...

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new figure. if you already have a figure, use `fig.set_size_inches()`. If you are using `plt.` commands use `fig = plt.gcf()` to **g**et  the **c**urrent **f**igure.